# Is memory space "locked" upon creation of object even if parameter is unused?

Tags: c++

PSEUDO CODE

```
Class Organ


Class Animal 
    member pointer Organ;
```

Let's say I call the default constructor on my object aka pointer to organ is null.

It will only used the pointer's memory size in my Animal object's total memory size, even if it's pointing at NULL ? right?

But once i assigned the object, my total memory usage will be Animal (including ptr) + sizeof(Organ)?

Comment: Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It is trivial to write actual code in this case and answering without it is kind of pointless.

Comment: The memory required to store an instance of a C++ class is fixed at compile time. The compiler works it out, and it's fixed no matter how the object is used. You can use the `sizeof` keyword to find out how big objects of a given type are.

Comment: Simply assigning a pointer to point at an object won't change your application's memory usage one way or another.  It's the call to the new operator that will allocate the additional memory space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It will only used the pointer's memory size in my Animal object's total memory size, even if it's pointing at NULL ? right?

Right.

> But once i assigned the object, my total memory usage will be Animal (including ptr) + sizeof(Organ)?

Right, plus some additional overhead which is usually present when doing heap allocation (`malloc()` or `new`).

Comment: Thank you very much